# react calling api indefiniely

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My main code looks as:

```
const [meta, setMeta] = useState({
    currentPage: 1,
    perPage: 20,
    searchQuery: "",
    sort: { order: "created_at", dir: "desc" },
    total: 0,
    totalPage: 0,
    query: "",
});

const customers = useSelector((state) => state.customers.customers);
const tableMeta = useSelector((state) => state.customers.tableMeta);

const data = React.useMemo(() => customers, [customers]);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(resetState());
    fetchData();
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("setmeta called");
    setMeta({
        ...meta,
        currentPage: tableMeta.current_page,
        perPage: tableMeta.per_page,
        total: tableMeta.total,
        totalPage: tableMeta.last_page,
    });
}, [tableMeta]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [meta]);

function fetchData() {
    dispatch(
        listCustomer(meta.currentPage, meta.perPage, meta.sort, meta.query)
    );
}
```

Here, meta is just the local state reference of meta data of table and `customers` and `tableMeta` are two state on redux where customers is the data list for a table and tableMeta is the deatails of meta data of a table like `pageSize, perPage, totalCount ...`

Here, on first apiCall, I have updated the `meta` state and I have also another `useEffect` hook to monitor the changes of `meta` state and thats the reason what causing it to loop forever,

after update of redux stae `tableMeta`, I have updated `meta` state and once meta updated its calling api and after api results `meta` state updated and in this way its going in loop.

So, staright forward, it looks like following code causing the loop:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [meta]);
```

Currently, I am using this useEffect because, when ever I try to navigate to different page I am updating currentPage under `meta` state

```
const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setMeta({
        ...meta,
        currentPage: page,
    });
};
```

so I need to call api after meta change. Where I am doing it in wrong way? How could I handle this scenario?

**Update**

I have updated the code to depends on single source of truth, but even on this approach again loop going on because still on first fetch `tableMeta` getting updated and I have to look `tableMeta` for case like when `handlePageChange` update the pageNumber

```
const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.customers.isLoading);
const customers = useSelector((state) => state.customers.customers);
const tableMeta = useSelector((state) => state.customers.tableMeta);

const data = React.useMemo(() => customers, [customers]);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(resetState());
    fetchData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [tableMeta]);

function fetchData() {
    dispatch(
        listCustomer(
            tableMeta.currentPage,
            tableMeta.perPage,
            tableMeta.sort,
            tableMeta.search
        )
    );
}

const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    console.log("dispatch action to update tableMeta.page");
};
const handlePageLengthChange = (per_page) => {
    console.log("dispatch action to update tableMeta.per_page");
};
const handleSearchQuery = (search) => {
    console.log("dispatch action to update tableMeta.search");
};
```

slice/reducer

```
CUSTOMER_LIST_SUCCESS: (state, action) => {
    state.customers = action.payload.list;
    let meta = action.payload.meta;

    state.tableMeta = {
        current_page: meta.current_page
            ? meta.current_page
            : initialState.tableMeta.current_page,
        per_page: meta.per_page
            ? meta.per_page
            : initialState.tableMeta.per_page,
        sort: meta.sort ? meta.sort : initialState.tableMeta.sort,
        total: meta.total ? meta.total : initialState.tableMeta.total,
        totalPage: meta.last_page
            ? meta.last_page
            : initialState.tableMeta.totalPage,
        search: meta.search
            ? meta.search
            : initialState.tableMeta.search,
    };

    state.isLoading = false;
},
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly it seems the `useEffect` that updates `meta` when `tableMeta` updates then triggers the other `useEffect` that results in `tableMeta` state being updated when `meta` is updated. This is the loop. Since these two seem related, or possibly a form of state duplication I think you should eliminate the local `meta` state and rely on the `tableMeta` as the source of truth.

Comment: use callback pattern to get rid of this issue.

Comment: @ManishSoni I am little new to react hooks, could you show me how could I do that with callback

Comment: @AayushDahal, Ok so this could be a long explanation, but there is a callback pattern that exist which you can use inside useEffect.  Please refer below article:- https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the code, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: any idea on this one guys?